# { 'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } }

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have get a response

```
console.log({'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } })
```

How to get only token in another variable in `node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var response = {'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } };
var myvariable = response['Name:Test']['token'];

console.log(myvariable);
```

Comment: console.log({'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } })

Answer (score 0):

We can use object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the token value, like so:

```js
let obj = {'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } };
let { 'Name:Test': { token: newVariable } } = obj;
console.log("Token:", newVariable );
```

Or we can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to get the same value

```js
let obj = {'Name:Test': { token: 738561, number: 2021.8 } };
let newVariable = obj['Name:Test']['token'];
console.log("Token:", newVariable);
```